# Using generic types to call overloaded functions

Tags: c#, list, generics, overload-resolution

`StreamWrite.Write` is overloaded for `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Double`, `Single`, `String` and many more.

Why do I need to use dynamic? When calling the `WriteList` Method, the compiler knows that it is called for `Int32`, `String`, ... .
So why can't I use **e** (of type **T=Int32**) directly in `StreamWrite.Write`?

```
public void WriteList<T>(List<T> list) 
{
  int count = list.Count();
  StreamWriter.Write(count);
  foreach(T e in list) 
  {
    dynamic d = e;
    StreamWriter.Write(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: See: [What's the difference, part one: Generics are not templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because overload resolution (in the absence of `dynamic`) happens at *compile* time, and at compile time, the actual type of `T` is unknown, since generics are a runtime feature.

The compiler doesn't know which method token of `Write` to include in the IL when compiling `WriteList`.

Comment: Does that mean that it is best practive to write an individual function for each type because there is no way to do this in a more general way?

Comment: @bebo - actually, your current workaround (`dynamic`) doesn't seem unreasonable, especially since because there's an `object` overload it will always succeed no matter what the actual type is.